# Drop down menu CSS3 on Hover

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Currently I am using `<span>Home<span>` on hover of an `anchor` element within a `li`. However, I need a drop-down on hover. Something like the same home `span` but two or three more items underneath it. Any help would be appreciated. Click for [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AmerSohail/tPHcd/)

[image]
!

Comment: That is quite tricky with your current design. Usually the icon would be the parent link then when you hovered then it would show its children but in your case when you hover you are just showing the name for the parent link. If you styled the items below the first child element differently then it could work. In terms of markup that would mean that within the home li you would need to add a ul to hold the submenu items. I am still not convinced that the deisgn will work for more than 1 level of drop down options

Comment: Initially you want to display the **Home** link only. Once you hover on **Home** link then you need to display the drop down with other entries (**About,Services, etc**). Is that you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you use `<ul>` and `<li>` rather than using `<span>`. Like what Parallel 2ne said it depends on your html markup. However you could also force it via Javascript/jQuery by creating a function that triggers automatically when you hover the `<span>` elements individually. When it triggers it applies `display:block` or `display:hidden` for the sub `<span>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it on css and html, without any js file.
The HTML Code you need :

```
<ul>
<li>
    <span>Menu 1</span>
    <div class="sub-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>sub1</li>
            <li>sub2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <span>Menu 2</span>
</li>
```

and here is the CSS you must attach :

```
li .sub-menu {
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    /*and more custom CSS as you need*/
}
li:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
}
```

You can use transition to animate your effects .

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at using icon fonts instead of pictures, makes the whole site much smaller if you are using many images like this and is much more efficient, making a jsfiddle for you now.